# Trying to decrypt the string encrypted from PHP and decrypted by Javascript(React JS) and android

Tags: javascript, php, android, reactjs

I am trying to encrypt the string from the PHP side and decrypt the same string from the Android side and the javascript side (React JS)

```
<?php

// Store a string into the variable which
// need to be Encrypted
$simple_string = "Hello!!! Shashank";

// Display the original string
echo "Original String: " . $simple_string;
echo "<br>";
// Store the cipher method
$ciphering = "AES-256-CTR";

// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
$options = 0;

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
$encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the encryption key
// $encryption_key = "5dmykEdrS1i1JM9AxQJkQou3ouzllG";

$encryption_key = "9989d55b6f25f4112feb3967ceef13b8";

// $keytoprint = $encryption_key;
// echo $keytoprint;
// echo "<br>";
// Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
$encryption = openssl_encrypt(
    $simple_string,
    $ciphering,
    $encryption_key,
    $options,
    $encryption_iv
);

// Display the encrypted string
echo "Encrypted String: " . $encryption . "\n";
echo "<br>";

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
$decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the decryption key
$decryption_key = $encryption_key;

// Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data
$decryption = openssl_decrypt(
    $encryption,
    $ciphering,
    $decryption_key,
    $options,
    $decryption_iv
);

// Display the decrypted string
echo "Decrypted String: " . $decryption;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

Output would be

```
Original String: Hello!!! Shashank
Encrypted String: SWSkckoj8iVZT9JJoGXVFB8=
Decrypted String: Hello!!! Shashank
```

The same way I did decrypt using the javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Decrypt String</title>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalbazaar/forge/main/lib/forge.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
        async function decryptString() {
            const encryptedString = "SWSkckoj8iVZT9JJoGXVFB8="; // Replace with your actual encrypted string
            const encryptionKey = "9989d55b6f25f4112feb3967ceef13b8"; // Replace with the actual 128-bit key
            
            try {
                const encryptedArrayBuffer = Uint8Array.from(atob(encryptedString), c => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer;
                const keyBuffer = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
                    'raw',
                    new TextEncoder().encode(encryptionKey),
                    'AES-CTR',
                    false,
                    ['decrypt']
                );
                const decryptedData = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
                    {
                        name: 'AES-CTR',
                        counter: new TextEncoder().encode('1234567891011121'),
                        length: 64
                    },
                    keyBuffer,
                    encryptedArrayBuffer
                );

                const decryptedString = new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedData);
                console.log("Decrypted String: " + decryptedString);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Decryption error: " + error);
            }
        }

        decryptString();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output would be in the console

```
Decrypted String: Hello!!! Shashank
```

So, All this stuff is working fine on the **`localhost`**

When I deploy the same code on the server I get the following error.

**`Decryption error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')`**

Does anyone has faced the issue on the server?

Comment: `crypto.subtle` is null in your JS

Comment: Are you using https://? crypto.subtle is only available in a secure context.

Comment: I hope you don't plan to hardcode your encryptedString and encryptionKey like this in production code, becuase the client will be able to see it, thus they will be able to decrypt it.

Comment: Hi @Saa no I am using the http not https

Comment: Hi @GrumpyCrouton what should be the possible solution ?

Comment: Why don't you just use https? Then everything will be encrypted during transmission anyway and you won't have to bother with this code.

Comment: @ShashankShah I would do ALL of the encryption/decryption on the server side (PHP) instead of javascript.

Comment: No, this is for the example purpose just to ensure it will work in this manner. I will not put the hardcoded string

Comment: @ShashankShah I'm not an expert on encryption/decryption, especially on the client side, but I am unaware of any way you could securely pass an encryption password to javascript without exposing it to the client.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton My requirement is there are certain URL that needs to be encrypted in the API response and should be decrypt by the android app and react js website that's why I am trying to decrypt by using javascript

Comment: It will NOT work using http. use https!

Comment: ...and then if you use HTTPS then **the data will already be encrypted automatically** so you won't need this code anyway.

Comment: Sure, let me try implementing the SSL and test the same case with https environment.

Comment: The only reason to use any extra encryption beyond HTTPS would be if a) you need to encrypt data when it is being stored on the client or server - but the code you've written isn't doing that, or b) there is some regulatory/security requirement relating to the sensitivity of the data you are transmitting which would require an extra level of encryption (e.g. perhaps bank transaction data, government-related data, or something like that). You haven't mentioned the existence of any such requirement or stipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crypto.subtle is only available in the Secure Context (HTTPS).

You'll get this error when crypto.subtle is not available. Check availability before using and also check the browser support: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_crypto_subtle

Comment: Works! thanks for the help!

Comment: @ShashankShah you still have the problem GrumpyCrouton pointed out though, where someone curious looking at your app/page would be able to locate the encryption keys. And you still haven't addressed the point I have made twice, that there is, in 99% of cases, no need for extra encryption of your data during tranmission, when you are already using HTTPS. One reason HTTPS exists is to stop developers from needing to worry about things like this in their everyday code.

Comment: @ShashankShah You should read the [use cases for the web crypto API](https://w3c.github.io/webcrypto/#use-cases), and see if any of them actually apply to your application or data. So far in your question and your code I have seen no evidence that any of them appear to be relevant.